# CentOS - how to install vsftpd for specific username to have specific directory access only?

Tags: centos, ftp, vsftpd

I have VSFTPD installed in CentOS. Where i have one username "lesstrust1", when the user login i want the user only can upload/download to this path `/var/www/html/oxwall`

```
$ yum install vsfptd
$ chkconfig vsftpd on
```

How do i tell VSFTPD to do that?

EDIT:

I have tried following based on man but does not work.

```
$ vim /etc/vsftpd/config.conf
# end of the file new line added
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd

$ vim /etc/vsftpd/username1
local_root=/var/www/html/oxwall

$ service vsftpd restart
```

Now, when FTP is connected as username1 it does not go to /var/www/html/oxwall but username1 can browse whole system including / or /etc all.

Is this a BUG?

Comment: Did you try `man vsftpd.conf`?

Comment: @Keith: YES Please see my edit above. I did but its not working

Answer (score 1):

You should set "lesstrust1" users home directory to /var/www/html/oxwall.

```
usermod --home /var/www/html/oxwall lesstrust1
```

And add the following line to your vsftpd configuration file.

```
chroot_local_user=YES
```

Comment: You should add that `/var/www/html/oxwall` must not be writeable by the user otherwise `vsftpd` will fail to start.